# set JMenuBar's background color?

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jmenubar

relatively straight-forward, how can I set the background color of a JMenuBar?

ive tried:

```
MenuBar m = new MenuBar() {

      void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
  g2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

but nothin'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, to start with, what you've shown is not a `JMenuBar`, it's `MenuBar`, there's a significant difference.  Try using a `JMenuBar`and use `setBackground` to change the background color

**Updated from feedback from Vulcan**

Okay, in the cases where `setBackground` doesn't work, this will ;)

```
public class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);

    }

}
```

Comment: JMenuBar#setBackground does not set the background color of a JMenuBar.

Comment: @Vulcan well, what'd you know, learning something every day :)

Comment: @user1332495 Just be careful, it might not work an all Look and Feel implementations, I think that's what Vulcan was trying to say

Comment: It didn't work in a test I just ran, but correct, I was using a custom L&F.  I will remove the downvote as soon as I can.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Vulcan, I couldn't get it take change under the Windows L&F so you're not entirely incorrect ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah, I just tested with default Windows 7 L&F and it worked, but your second solution is far safer and works in more cases.

Comment: Glad that was solved! (by that i mean both the question and dispute)

Comment: BasicMenuUI returns array of Colors, UImanager.put() or Painter<>

Comment: @mKorbel I was trying to look into that.  Better idea

Comment: @MadProgrammer do not to take my comments as attack to your person, I leaving my comments for most posters here, sure and I know how to down_vote too, but your progress (on this forum) is excellent

Comment: @mKorbel Never do and I appreciate the feedback, your suggestion on the BasicMenuUI is an excellent one, takes less effort and is backwards compatible, what's to dislike ;) - I also like to get a different perspective on these problems as well

Comment: be sure I hate that too (Painter in only one way how to do for Nimbus), this is reason why a few good custom look and feels is there, why bothering with that :-)

Answer (score 6):

With **MadProgrammer**'s approach you will get menubar background painted twice - once by the UI (it could be gradient on Windows for example, which takes some time to paint) and once by your code in **paintComponent** method (atop of the old background).

Better replace menubar UI by your own one based on BasicMenuBarUI:

```
    menuBar.setUI ( new BasicMenuBarUI ()
    {
        public void paint ( Graphics g, JComponent c )
        {
            g.setColor ( Color.RED );
            g.fillRect ( 0, 0, c.getWidth (), c.getHeight () );
        }
    } );
```

You can also set that UI globally for all menubars so that you don't need to use your specific component each time you create menubar:

```
UIManager.put ( "MenuBarUI", MyMenuBarUI.class.getCanonicalName () );
```

MyMenuBarUI class here is your specific UI for all menubars.

Comment: wooohooo till now I saw Xxx.class.getCanonicalName() second time, great desing +1

Comment: @mKorbel thanks, and i really don't understand why most of the developers hardcode the class names (even if they re not going to be changed ever).

Comment: I've tried your second approach but somehow doesn't have any effect. Where should I look for the problem?

Comment: @Czechnology You might not have a special static method "createUI" added in your UI class so it doesn't affect the UI at all. This is the most common mistake when creating a custom UI.